# Issue with gem "railties" when I try to upgrade to Rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I'm trying to upgrade from Rails 3.1.10 to 3.2.11 and I've run into this issue when I run bundle install:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (= 3.1.4) ruby depends on
      railties (~> 3.1.0) ruby

    rails (= 3.2.11) ruby depends on
      railties (3.2.11)
```

What's going on here? I don't understand what the railties gem is, and since it's not listed in my Gemfile I'm not sure if I should explicitly put a line about it in my Gemfile.

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "3.1.4"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'asset_sync'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

railties is - Rails internals: application bootup, plugins, generators, and rake tasks. From the [rubygems website](http://rubygems.org/gems/railties).

The Runtime Dependencies for it are

- actionpack = 3.2.11
- activesupport = 3.2.11
- rack-ssl ~> 1.3.2
- rake >= 0.8.7
- rdoc ~> 3.4
- thor < 2.0, >= 0.14.6

The problem being that you have specified your sass-rails gem to version 3.1.4 which depends on the older version of railties which is not in rails 3.2.11 the newer version of sass-rails 3.2.6 will work with the newer version of rails (and railties).

Comment: Did this help at all or are you still having issues?

Comment: sorry, I was sick I hadn't checked StackOverflow. This was perfect, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: So what would your gemfile look like?